# Accept number of inputs based on a number given at runtime in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unix

Accept an integer n 
Based on n, accept n inputs 
Ex:
At runtime 
n = 2 
Then 2 inputs of type string should be accepted

Ex:
At runtime 
n = 3 
Then 3 inputs of type string should be accepted

Comment: What have you tried and where does it fail? If you include this and phrase your question more like a question (and not an order), people are more likely to help and less likely to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = []
n.times {array << gets.chomp}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i

array = []

array[n] = gets.chomp while (n -= 1) >= 0

# array will contain the inputs... 
# array.pop will return them in order of input
```